# Eigen values of matrices

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $A$ be a square matrix and $(\text{adj} A)$ be its adjoint, show that the eigen values of matrices $A$. $(\text{adj} A)$ and $A\cdot(\text{adj} A)$ are real.

I tried to solve by using the equation $A\cdot(\text{adj} A) = |A|\cdot I = A\cdot(\text{adj} A)$, then the eigen values are coming to be $|A|$.

How to say $|A|\in\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: You do have the problem that if $A$ doesn't have full rank, its determinant is zero, but the adjoint/adjugate still makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

This is not true. To see this, pick $A = \begin{pmatrix} i & 1 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$. If you restrict the elements of $A$ to be real, however, the statement is true.

Comment: yeah you are correct .But the question was asked in an exam.If elements of A are real , |A| will definitely be real and the statement is true

Comment: Then you should consider contacting your teacher:)